# How to merge to dataframes based on Interval condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two data frames of the format

[image]

[image]

I want to concatenate the two such that I have a resultant table of the format
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas outer merge.
For example if your first dataframe is df1 and second is df2 then,

> result_df = df1.merge(df2, how="outer", left_on="Time 15 Min",right_on="Time Event")

See [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for more info.